# DialogFlow integration. How can i do it?

Tags: node.js, integration, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How can i make integration between DialogFlow and my information system using inline editor?

Can i use inline editor and Webhook at moment.

When turning inline editor, Webhook area is switching off.

I want to send  intent parameters to my information system.

Answer (score 1):

The Inline Editor is just a shortcut to setting up a webhook fulfillment - it is doing that for you instead of you having to set it up.

The Inline Editor runs on Google Cloud Functions for Firebase, so if you can do it using that platform, you should be able to do it. One limitation of the default configuration is that no outside network connections are allowed. If you want to make outside connections, you will need to [upgrade to a paid plan, such as the Blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), however there is a base level of usage that doesn't have a charge.